# How to underline text in textField xml?

Tags: jasper-reports

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Sehubungan "+$F{contractnumber}+" tanggal "]]></textFieldExpression
```

How do I underline just `$F{contractnumber}`???

Comment: See also: http://practicaltypography.com/underlining.html

Answer (score 4):

Use styled text.

```
<textField>
  ...
  <textElement markup="styled"/>
  <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Sehubungan <style isUnderline=\"true\">"+$F{contractnumber}+"</style> tanggal "]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but this will help someone using Jasper Studio and looking for the UI way.

- Select your text field.
  In properties, look for this and follow steps 1,2,3 as shown:
  [image: image containing steps]

1. Select Text Field from properties
2. Select Markup as Styles
3. Select Underline from Font.